# NullReferenceException using CloudRail LinkedIn Service

Tags: .net, redirect, nullreferenceexception, linkedin-api, cloudrail

I am trying to connect to the LinkedIn API using CloudRail's LinkedIn .NET dll. I have the following code to set-up the LinkedIn service for my app:

```
static void Initialize()
{
CloudRail.AppKey = "5-------9";
LinkedIn service = new LinkedIn(
    new LocalReceiver(8082),
    "78---------s", //clientId
    "X----------Y", //clientSecret
    "http://localhost:8082/",
    "state");

service.Login();
}
```

Before reaching login, I get this error:

"System.SystemException: 'ServiceCode Error in function authenticate at 3: awaitCodeRedirect $L2 $L0 ? $P0.redirectUri'

Inner Exception
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

How can I fix this to correctly set up the LinkedIn CloudRail connection for the API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that if you are using the DLL, is that you are using the correct [dependencies](https://github.com/CloudRail/cloudrail-si-dotnet-sdk#dependencies-required-for-dll)